# Change label text with jQuery but not other label elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 radio buttons and each of them inside a label.

```
<fieldset>
<label><input type="radio" name="invoice_type" value="Receipt"> Receipt</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="invoice_type" value="Invoice"> Invoice</label>
</fieldset>
```

I tried to change the label text with jQuery with this code but it replaces entire label content, including the radio boxes.

```
$('fieldset>label:eq(0)').text('Some text');
$('fieldset>label:eq(1)').text('Some text');
```

how i can replace only the label text without touching the radio boxes?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you the input inside the label?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it's a standard technique to allow the related text (Receipt/Invoice) to be clickable and also update the radio, without needing `for=` and IDs.   Try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f91uovjw/)

Comment: Simplest solution is to put the text in a span and target that.  Alternative is to find textContent.

Comment: From [eq-selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/#eq1) - As of jQuery 3.4, the `:eq` pseudo-class *is deprecated*

Comment: i can't change the html source. it's a wocommerce store. i have added this extra fields with woocommerce checkout fields plugin. so i can't add <span> or <label for>.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider rearranging your HTML.

```js
$('fieldset>label:eq(0)').text('Some teqxt');
$('fieldset>label:eq(1)').text('Some text');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
<label for="label1">Receipt</label>
<input type="radio" id="label1" name="invoice_type" value="Receipt">
<label for="label2">Invoice</label>
<input type="radio" id="label2" name="invoice_type" value="Invoice">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Clicking the text works, you can change the location of the labels in the DOM to put it around the other way.

Comment: Was still editing the post while you were posting haha

Comment: i can't change the html source. it's a wocommerce store. i have added this extra fields with woocommerce checkout fields plugin. so i can't add <span> or <label for>.

Answer (score 0):

Using simple vanilla JS this is easy (no clue about jQuery though, stopped using that in 2015), and does not require any changes in the markup:

```js
document.querySelector('fieldset>label').childNodes[1].textContent = ' foo';
document.querySelector('fieldset>label+label').childNodes[1].textContent = ' bar';
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <label><input type="radio" name="invoice_type" value="Receipt"> Receipt</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="invoice_type" value="Invoice"> Invoice</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: With this code it changes only the first label. not the second.

document.querySelector('fieldset>label').childNodes[1].textContent = ' Text 1';
document.querySelector('fieldset>label').childNodes[2].textContent = ' Text 2';

Comment: Added changing of the second label's text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not require to change your HTML and uses `jquery`:

```js
$('fieldset>label:eq(0)').contents()[1].textContent = 'Some teqxt';
$('fieldset>label:eq(1)').contents()[1].textContent = 'Some text';
```

If you have multiple tags inside the `<label>` tag you can use the more correct filtering version:

```js
$('fieldset>label:eq(0)').contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType === 3; })[0].textContent = 'Some teqxt';
$('fieldset>label:eq(1)').contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType === 3; })[0].textContent = 'Some text';
```

Answer (score 0):

To make minimal changes to your layout and still not need an `id=` and related `for=`:

- add a `span` to wrap your text and target the span

this also has the added bonus of allowing some styling to be added to the span, eg for consistent spacing

```
label>input+span { margin-left:0.75em; }
```

without relying on additional spaces in both the original markup and in the replacement text

```js
$("button").click(() => {
  $('fieldset>label:eq(0)>span').text('Some text');
  $('fieldset>label:eq(1)>span').text('Some other text');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="invoice_type" value="Receipt">
    <span>Receipt</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="invoice_type" value="Invoice">
    <span>Invoice</span>
  </label>
</fieldset>
<button>click me</button>
```

---

**Note**

> https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/#eq1
>
> As of jQuery 3.4, the `:eq` pseudo-class **is deprecated**. Remove it from your selectors and filter the results later using `.eq()`.

left it in above so that it matches OPs code more closest, the alternative would be:

```
$("fieldset>label").eq(0).find(span)
```

or target the individual label directly

```
$("input[value='Receipt']").next()
```

(based on the current layout)

Comment: No need to change the HTML, see my answer.

Comment: Correct, as noted in my comment, add a span *or* use textContent - as you provided an answer using textContent, I've provided an answer using a span.

Comment: i can't change the html source. it's a wocommerce store. i have added this extra fields with woocommerce checkout fields plugin. so i can't add <span> or <label for>.